# Python - Pickle non-picklable object

Tags: python, pickle

I have an object which I want to pickle it. but inside it there is another object which is **not picklable**.
There is a function inside my **none picklable** object which serialize this object for me.
So now how can I pickle the big class object?

Comment: Sample classes/code?

Comment: By using `__getstate__` or `__reduce__`, as described [here in the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-inst).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.